# Throw a fair die repeatedly until I have thrown three sixes

Tags: probability

I play a game in which I have to throw a fair die repeatedly until I have thrown three sixes, after which I stop and note the total number of throws. What is the probability that I take six throws?

I did $(1/6)^3 \times (5/6)^3$ and this gave me $0.00268$ to 3.s.f.

This doesn't seem right as couldn't this be achieved in many ways by throwing the die to be 6 in different orders? E.g. $6,6,6$, non six,non six, non six OR 6,non six, non six, 6, 6, non six

Could anyone explain this?

Comment: Your analysis of the issue is right.  To get the right answer quickly, note that we get the third six on the $6$-th try if and only if (i) we have exactly $2$ sixes in the first $5$ trials and (ii) we get a six on the $6$-th trial. To find the probability of (i) is a probably familiar binomial distribution problem. Or else, equivalently but more slowly, enumerate all the different orders in which it could happen (you started doing that) and add up the probabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first $5$ throws exactly $2$ sixes must be thrown.

The probability of this event is $\binom52\left(\frac16\right)^2\left(\frac56\right)^3$.

After that a six must be thrown so we end up with a probability of: $$\binom52\left(\frac16\right)^3\left(\frac56\right)^3$$

Comment: So the answer is 0.0536?

Comment: I haven't a calculator at hand, but I think it is 0.026791838.;)

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You would need two $6$'s in the first five throws, and third $6$ in sixth throw. There are $\binom52$ ways to order the first five throws, so the final result is:
$$\binom52\left(\frac56\right)^3\left(\frac16\right)^3$$

Comment: So the answer is 0.0536?

Comment: No, $\binom52=10$, so the expression evaluates to $0.02679...$